# pjsip enable loudspeaker on ios des not work

Tags: ios, pjsip

I use this code  to try to enable loudspeaker on iOS device.

```
pjmedia_aud_dev_route route = PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_ROUTE_LOUDSPEAKER;
pj_status_t status = pjsua_snd_set_setting(PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_ROUTE, &route, PJ_FALSE);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS){
             NSLog(@"Error enabling loudspeaker");
}
```

I know I can use `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute` but I want to enable it by pjsip because then I can pass `PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_ROUTE_BLUETOOTH` to route and enable bluetooth.

I use pjsip 1.8.5 on iOS 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated pjsip to version 2.0.1 and the code above is working with no problem.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am using PJSIP version 2.2.1, I tried above code and that is not working. Any reason or any update do you think needed in above code?

Comment: Hi Alex, have you any solution for pjsip Bluetooth? we are using pjsip 2.6.
call using Bluetooth then voice not hear.so if you have a solution related to this please help me.
Thank you